# angular js date input formatting

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a date input in an AngularJS app and have trouble formatting the date.  I have created a plnkr to illustrate my issue:http://plnkr.co/edit/LbQIPG?p=preview

My issue is that regardless of the date format that I am receiving back from SQL Server (I put two sample dates in the plnkr 2013-07-11T00:00:00.000 and 2013-07-11), the Javascript Date object is applying a time zone code and affecting the display of my date in the input field by displaying 07/10/2013 instead of the correct date of 7/11/2013.  I just want the date that was actually returned from the database, I don't want the timezone to be applied at all, only the date is relevant to me, not time.  Do I need to create a custom directive to accurately display the date that I want by getting the ISO date time and then assigning that date string to my input? Or is there a better solution.  Here is a sample of the code I was thinking I might need to use to format my date in a directive:

```
var newDate =  $scope.dataBaseData.myDate.toISOString();
newDate = new Date(newDate);
$scope.dataBaseData.myDate= new Date((newDate.getUTCMonth() +1) + "/" +newDate.getUTCDate() + "/" + newDate.getUTCFullYear());
```

Comment: You should have your SQL server send back strings that include a timezone --- and for sanity, the DB should store all dates in UTC. Javascript and angular then have many facilities to display those dates in the desired format + timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs uses ISO8601 spec for date and time. You need to shift the timezone if you want JavaScript to parse the ISO8601 string correctly.

However if you create the Date object like this

```
$scope.thing1 = new Date(2013, 6, 11);  (month is 0 based.)
```

This is dumped as `Thu Jul 11 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` in console.

The date object automatically picks up the time zone and it will render correctly to be 07/11/2013.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I believe that the day is actually 1 based and only the month is zero based.  But this response is essentially the same solution that I had suggested at the bottom of my post. I extract each one of the date objects from the date and reassign the scope's date object the same way that you did.

Comment: @mvargos Thanks. The thing is if you can make your API to return dates in UTC, it will be much easier for UI to handle.